# Creation of windows phone 8 application using visual studio 2012

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have Visual studio 2012 installed on my machine.
Is there a nuget package available for windows phone application development?
I have windows 7 OS.
Also is there a way to develop Windows 8 applications on Windows 7 OS? I don't want to install Windows 8 OS.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. **You cannot develop Windows Phone 8 application on Windows 7** (I assume you meant Windows Phone 8 applications).

The longer answer is here in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) system requirements.

Basically you need to have

- Hardware-assisted virtualization.
- 64-bit version of Windows 8 Pro edition or higher.

There are many nuget packages for Windows Phone application available. Without knowing your specific requirements I would still suggest you to start with MVVM Light if you haven't.

Answer (score 0):

Just install Win8 or 8.1 on dual boot as I did. You won't have any issues and I must say that it's not that bad actually, I even kind of like it now.